# Metric on a Class of Functions Mapping to a Metric Space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a nonempty set and $(Y,\rho)$ a nonempty metric space. Let $Y^X$ denote the set of mappings from $X$ to $Y$. Define $\pi:Y^X\times Y^X\to[0,\infty)$ as follows: for any $f,g\in Y^X$, let $$\pi(f,g)\equiv\min\left\{1,\sup_{x\in X}\rho(f(x),g(x))\right\}.$$

I need to trick with the “min” in order to make sure $\pi$ is finite even when the supremum is not.

Question: is $(Y^X,\pi)$ a metric space? I'm almost sure it is, but I just need some external verification to be fully convinced. Thank you in advance for sharing your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it's true. All of the metric space axioms except possibly the triangle inequality are very easy to check, so let's focus on the latter.

Let $f, g, h \in Y^X$. Of course it is automatic by definition that $0 \leq \pi(f, h) \leq 1$, so if either $\pi(f, g) = 1$ or $\pi(g, h) = 1$, it is immediate that $\pi(f, h) \leq \pi(f, g) + \pi(g, h)$. If not, then we have $\pi(f, g) = \sup_{x \in X} \rho(f(x), g(x))$ and $\pi(g, h) = \sup_{x \in X} \rho(g(x), h(x))$. Then for any $z \in X$ we have

$$\rho(f(z), h(z)) \leq \rho(f(z), g(z)) + \rho(g(z), h(z)) \leq \pi(f, g) + \pi(g, h)$$

whence $\pi(f, h) \leq \sup_{z \in X} \rho(f(z), h(z)) \leq \pi(f, g) + \pi(g, h)$.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! @user43208